# How to get rid of extra whitespace to the right of a slider?

Tags: html, css, flexslider

Here is my website (http://fitness.jermaineforbes.com/), I have a slideshow that is made from the "flexslider" library. The slider works, but there is extra whitespace to right of the webpage. I tried to add overflow:hidden to a lot of different places but the whitespace is still present. I don't see a padding or margin issue that might create extra space. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a previous and next link. The next links is set with `right-50px` so it is outside the viewport on the right side.

To remove the space on the right side you can override the CSS rule with the following CSS:

```
.flex-direction-nav .flex-next {
    right:0 !important;
}
```

Another solution would be to remove the previous and next link if not needed!

Comment: this is the solution. `overflow-x: hidden` is not the right way because it will remove the `elastic bounce effect`.

Comment: Man, thank you so much for this answer. I just  changed the option directionNav:false . That removes the next and previous links

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple. You just want some css to fix this. Insert the css given below in your page.

```
body { 
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**overflow-x** css property hides or shows the x overflow

Answer (score 0):

Use this on html

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```